# Java - double*int arithmatic displays with two decimals OR several decimal places

Tags: java, formatting, double

New to Java. I am writing a simple program for a project. It is a program that allows a user to buy pizza. It has a running total and an order summary at the end. I am using these lines to keep the total & subtotal:

```
switch(mainMenuAnswer) //Switch statement to get correct pricing multiplied by # of desired pizza ordered  
{            
    case 1:
        total = total + (pizzaPrices1[otherAnswer - 1] * count);
        miniTotal = pizzaPrices1[otherAnswer - 1] * count;
        break;

    case 2:
        total = total + (pizzaPrices2[otherAnswer - 1] * count);
        miniTotal = pizzaPrices2[otherAnswer - 1] * count;
        break;

    case 3:
        total = total + (pizzaPrices3[otherAnswer - 1] * count);
        miniTotal = pizzaPrices3[otherAnswer - 1] * count;
        break;

    case 4:
        total = total + (pizzaPrices4[otherAnswer - 1] * count);
        miniTotal = pizzaPrices4[otherAnswer - 1] * count;
        break;

    case 5:
        total = total + (pizzaPrices5[otherAnswer - 1] * count);
        miniTotal = pizzaPrices5[otherAnswer - 1] * count;
        break;

}
```

Total and miniTotal are doubles that starts out at 0.0, while the prices are in a ##.## format, followed by count, which is an integer value. They are being multiplied.

Sometimes I get a good answer, such as $42.35 (random number), but sometimes I get:

```
 How many large pizzas?: 4

---------------------------------------------------------

Your current order total is $151.91

---------------------------------------------------------

Specialty Pizza Menu

1) Meat Lovers
2) BBQ Chicken
3) Hawaiian
4) Chicken-Bacon Ranch
5) Vegetarian
6) Exit Menu

Your choice?: 6

Order Summary:

Type                   Size          Quantity    Price
---------------------------------------------------------
Meat Lovers            Large         5           $99.94999999999999 
BBQ Chicken            Large         4           $51.96 

Order total: $151.91
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that everything is being formatted (just in case) to two decimal places, except the double values directly under "Price". I would easily format it as well, but I don't know how. The line of code to format is:

```
System.out.printf("%-22s %-13s %-11d %-2s \n" , typeArray[i], sizeArray[i], quantityArray[i], priceArray[i]); //Formatting
```

I tried using `%-11.2d` but it gives me an error. Anybody know what is going on? I assume it is something with the variable double and memory bits, but what is a good solution?

NOTE: priceArray is a STRING array, in $##.## format.

Comment: Using doubles for currency is a bad idea (as you're finding). You need a decimal datatype or just keep all your calculations in pennies

Comment: I didn't know about the Currency class until I was half done with this program, otherwise I would have used it

Comment: @Andremoniy being that I am in my first java class coming from C++, and having to follow a specific format for our program based on what my professor gave me (which is why the program looks and is formatted the way it is), I can assure you I know what loops are, among many other things. I said your comment was useless because that is exactly what it is. I couldn't care less where you buy pizza from, and you have no right to complain about my style of writing considering we need to follow a strict format for the programming project (which of course you wouldn't know but still decided to rant)

Comment: And I want to add that this question should be closed because you didn't provide real MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Andremoniy Again, you are getting completely off-topic. How I write my code in a different language is completely up to me and what is required of the program. I couldn't care less if you have any sort of degree in this field if you are being a stubborn, hard-headed, elitist prick about it. This is a forum to help others with their problems, not to complain about formatting. The way this is formatted is decided upon the professor, and I followed it with what little knowledge of Java I have

Comment: @bankey mcve stands for minimum complete and verifiable example. It's about how you write your question not about the standard of the code. It means give us enough to run your program and see the problem (and no more)

Comment: Before his comment were removed, he was talking about the quality of the code. I am still trying to get used to MCVE. I am always torn between adding too much and adding too little and can't find a common ground

Comment: @bankey Seeing it running often makes it a world easier to understand; you can play with it and live debug it. Including everything you need to run (including the main method) will give you a much higher answer rate, and sometimes you'll find the answer yourself while you're cutting the code down to a minimum example. In this case I would have suggested cutting out all the pizza stuff, finding an equation that gives the 99.9499999 and then trying to format that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since price array is a string array, you cannot give it number formatting. Keep it as a double array and use the double to 2 decimal string conversion at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The use of 11.2d is used for double formating, while your array is a String. You might want to use some string method to format it the way you want it to be.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Find "." and then add two more index to it and cut off the rest.